# reactjs unknown: unexpected token on React.createElement

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I've got a .jsx file and I'm writing in es6. I have a component and I want it to return a good ole link! I copied the exact link from the [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html). Here is my code...

```
class PanelContent extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      React.createElement('a', {href: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/'}, 'Hello!')
    )
  }
}
```

And the error I'm receiving is, `SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (4:35)`. The error is pointing at the `:` in `href`. So please anyone help.

Comment: Are you transpiling it through babel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the parenthesis in the return of the render function react thinks you're going to be writing in jsx if you don't want to inline your html you could do: **EDIT: This first example seems like it should work with or without parenthesis**

```
class PanelContent extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return React.createElement('a', {href: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/'}, 'Hello!')
  }
}
```

or if you want to use jsx (make sure you have a processor running):

```
class PanelContent extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <a href='https://facebook.github.io/react/'>Hello!</a>
    ) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a correct answer :( Having the parenthesis will have no effect on output in this case. http://jsbin.com/hawamodati/edit?html,js,output

Comment: you're right!  I remember running into an issue where the return wasn't working with the parenthesis, unfortunately I'm not sure what exactly is was.

Comment: Ok gents, I figured it out. I misread the documentation. I am using a .jsx transpiler and so I need to write in .jsx. However, the `React.createElement('a', {href: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/'}, 'Hello!')` is Javascript. I just needed to straight up use `<a href='https://facebook.github.io/react/'>Hello!</a>` because that is a .jsx formate.  I thought their documentation said, with jsx this becomes this, but it was just saying write the former if .js and the latter if .jsx.